# Fade in content

Tags: jquery

This code hides #title, sets the text, then fades it in.

```
$('#title').fadeOut(0).text(data.name).fadeIn();
```

Is there a better way to do the fadeOut(0) part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to hide the element instantly, then fade it in with new text, do this:

```
$('#title').hide().text(data.name).fadeIn();
```

---

If instead you want it to animate, your code doesn't wait for anything to happen: it starts to fade in, then sets text instantly, and then fades out (without waiting for anything to finish).

Use callbacks, which are anonymous functions which get called after the parent function has executed completely:

```
$('#title').fadeOut(function() {
  $(this).text(data.name).fadeIn();
});
```

I really wish jQuery's functions could be chained that easily...

Good luck!

Comment: you mean it sets the text *then* fades in. and i think that's exactly what he wanted. he wouldn't have used `0` if he wanted the fadeout to be animated..i think he just wanted to hide it instantaneously, as in your second example.

Comment: Sorry, when I see `fadeIn()`, I see it fading in, hence animating. Lemme re-arrange my post...

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
$('#title').fadeOut(100, function() {

    $(this).text(data.name).fadeIn(100);     

});
```

This version will not change the text until the element has finished animated.